# Refresh JPanel content on tab switch

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtabbedpane

I'm writing a simple UI just to get the hang of things. I have a tabbed window with two tabs, one has a button that counts up an integer, the other has a text field showing the content of said integer. Or at least that's the plan.

Everything works just fine if I stuff everything into one class. I can access tab 1 from my actionlistener and change the text field in tab 1 from the button press in tab 2. But I don't want my entire program to be in one class, obviously.

And here I have no idea what to do: I need to tell the textfield in the Class Tab1 to change on the button press in the Class Tab2. What's the right thing to do here? My first thought was to hand over an instance of Tab1 in the creation of Tab2, so I could do tab1.changeText(). But that would get messy quickly once I'd get more tabs that interact with each other. So, instead, I want to update the content of the first tab every time it is opened, but I don't know how to do that. And I don't know if that's the right thing to do, either. So, help!

Here's some code. "content" is an instance of Content, a class handling all the logic like adding to the counter.

Main GUI Class:

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {

  //Stuff..

  JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
  tabs.addTab("One", new Tab1(content));
  tabs.addTab("Two", new Tab2(content));

  //Stuff..
```

Tab 1:

```
public class Tab1 extends JPanel {

  public Tab1(Content content) {
    JPanel tab1 = new JPanel();
    //Stuff..
    JTextField tfCount = new JTextField(content.getCounter(), 10);
    tab1.add(tfCount);

    this.add(tab1);

    //Stuff..
```

Tab 2:

```
public class Tab2 extends JPanel {

  public Tab2(Content content) {
    JPanel tab2 = new JPanel();
    //Stuff..

    JButton btnCount2 = new JButton("Count");
    btnCount2.addActionListener(new TestListener(this.content));

    tab2.add(btnCount2);
    this.add(tab2);
  }

  private class TestListener implements ActionListener {

    Content content;

    public TestListener(Content content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        this.content.addToCounter(1);
    }
}
```

Now, if all of that would be in one class (plus subclasses), I could just access tfCount from Tab2 and do tfCount.setText(content.getCounter());. Now tfCount is in a different class, though, and I cannot access it, unless I hand over an instance of Tab1 to Tab2 (like tabs.addTab("Two", new Tab2(content, Tab1);). Couldn't I instead get Tab1 to repaint itself whenever it is opened, like having a method that executes tfCount.setText(content.getCounter()) in Tab1 whenever it is opened, or something along those lines? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: Have you thought of using `Getters` and `Setters`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With you controls separated in this manner you have a view choices...

### You Could...

Share an instance of each "tab" with each of the other tabs, allowing them to either access the others controls or attach listeners across each other.  This is very tightly coupled and messy.

The other problem is, does the button really care about the text field or visa versa...

### You Could...

Create a simple model that contains the current `int` value and provides a means to change that value.

The model would have the capacity to fire a `ChangeEvent` (for example) when the value is changed, which interested parties could listen for and update themselves accordingly.

This decouples the code, reducing the complexity and greatly increasing the flexibility and reuse of various elements of your code.

This is commonly known as an observer pattern and is widely used in Swing.

### A possible (listener) example...

For me, I always start with an interface, this describes the absolute minimum requirements that must be meet in order to achieve the required goal.  Each tab will want to know the current value, be able to set the next value and listener for changes to the model...

```
public interface NumberModel {
    public int getValue();
    public void setValue(int value);

    public void addChangeListener(ChangeListener listener);
    public void removeChangeListener(ChangeListener listener);
}
```

An `abstract` implementation deals with the more "common" implementation details, things that a concrete implementation won't want to have to implement, as it's common enough to all implementations.  In this case, that would the listener management...

```
public abstract class AbstractNumberModel implements NumberModel {

    private List<ChangeListener> listeners;

    public AbstractNumberModel() {
        listeners = new ArrayList<>(25);
    }

    @Override
    public void addChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    protected ChangeListener[] getChangeListeners() {
        // FIFO...
        List<ChangeListener> copy = new ArrayList<>(listeners);
        Collections.reverse(copy);
        return copy.toArray(copy.toArray(new ChangeListener[listeners.size()]));
    }

    protected void fireStateChanged() {
        ChangeListener[] listeners = getChangeListeners();
        if (listeners != null && listeners.length > 0) {
            ChangeEvent evt = new ChangeEvent(this);
            for (ChangeListener listener : listeners) {
                listener.stateChanged(evt);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, a concrete implementation, which deals with the implementation specific details...

```
public class DefaultNumberModel extends AbstractNumberModel {

    private int value;

    public DefaultNumberModel() {
    }

    public DefaultNumberModel(int value) {
        setValue(value);
    }

    @Override
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(int num) {
        if (num != value) {
            value = num;
            fireStateChanged();
        }
    }

}
```

We could be a slightly more flexible model by doing something like `public interface NumberModel<N extends Number>` which would allow you define models that could hold `Integer`, `Double`, `Float` and `Long` for example, but I'll leave that to you.

Each of you tab views will need a `setModel(NumberModel)` method, so you can pass the model it.  In these methods, you will attach a listener to the model and `get` the current value so that the model and view are in sync.

Comment: Hm, how do I fire a ChangeEvent (or any other kind of Event) so it gets caught by a Listener?

Comment: First, your model needs a list of listeners (say ChangeListener). When the value changes, you walk the list and call the stateChanged method